# Why is this html append structured differently than the array structure

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I have two for loops which builds my html structure.

The outer loop builds each row `'<div class="row">'`
before the code jumps into the nested for loop which builds each column in the row `'<div class="col-sm-1">'+data[k].value+'</div>'`
before the row-div is closed in the outer loop.

```js
var i;
var n;
var k = 0;

for (i = 0; i < createRows; i++) {
    htmlArray.push('<div class="row">')
    console.log("creating row")
    for (n = 0; n < variableAmount; n++) {
        htmlArray.push('<div class="col-sm-1">' + data[k].value + '</div>')
        k++
    }
    htmlArray.push('</div>')
    console.log("ending row")
}
console.log(htmlArray)
$("#wrapper").append(htmlArray);
```

The `console.log(htmlArray)` is showing the expected output and structure which is `row` containing all the `col-sm-1` divs, before building a new `row` div, but when the array is appended to `#wrapper` I get a structure similar to this:

```html
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="col-sm-1"></div>
<div class="col-sm-1"></div>
<div class="col-sm-1"></div>
```

Where the `row` div is closed without containing any column div.

Wanted structure from console.log of htmlArray:

[image: console.log]

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: The append is not appending the same structure as seen in the array. It closes the Row div before the colum divs. What am I missing here?

Comment: HTML elements are appended as units, you can't append opening and closing tags separately. Append `htmlArray.join('')` instead of the array.

Comment: @Teemu But they are pushed in the array together, before appended. They are not appended separatly(?). Wanted structure is console.log of htmlArray.

Comment: JQuery will iterate through the array, and append every member individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is you append an array. You can use [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it to build the final HTML structure.

```js
const finalHTML = htmlArray.join('');
$("#wrapper").append(finalHTML);
```

Comment: Working solution. Thank you.